# Сортировка массива по значениям другого массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Исходный массив

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array ( [id_spacecom] => 18 [num_block] => 15 ) 

[1] => Array ( [id_spacecom] => 12 [num_block] => 9 ) 

[2] => Array ( [id_spacecom] => 19 [num_block] => 16 )
```

)

Как его отсортировать по `num_block`, исходя из сортировки этого массива, не прибегая к разбору `foreach` ?

```
Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 15 [2] => 16 )
```

Спасибо!

Comment: чего чего? исходя из чего отсортировать? второй приведенный массив это что?

Comment: во втором массиве находятся значения , которые соответствуют ключу num_block

Comment: это я вижу, там задан нужный порядок или что? ибо пока что они там просто в порядке возрастания.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php .......... http://php.net/manual/ru/function.uasort.php

Comment: во втором массив нужный порядок, могут цифры произвольно располагаться !

Answer (score 1):

Исходные данные:

```
$data = [
     [ 'id_spacecom' => 18, 'num_block' => 15 ],
     [ 'id_spacecom' => 12, 'num_block' => 9  ],
     [ 'id_spacecom' => 19, 'num_block' => 16 ],
];

$order = [15,16,9 ];
```

меняем местами элементы и ключи массива `$order`:

```
$sort = array_flip($order);
```

и используем его при сортировке с помощью `usort`

```
usort($data, function($a,$b) use($sort){
                return $sort[$a['num_block']] - $sort[$b['num_block']];
            });
```

Comment: при повторении значений `num_block` поведение будет не определено.