# php фильтрация многомерного массива по значению элементов другого массива

Tags: php

Имеется 2 массива - одномерный типа

```
`$categories = [Bird, Fish, Dog, Cat]`
```

и ассоциативный

```
`$pets = [
 0 => ['name' => 'Jacky',       'type' => 'Bird'],
 1 => ['name' => 'Rich',        'type' => 'Bird'],
 2 => ['name' => 'Nemo',        'type' => 'Fish'],
 3 => ['name' => 'Snoopy',      'type' => 'Dog'],
 4 => ['name' => 'Mr. Perkins', 'type' => 'Cat']
 ]`
```

Нужно вывести ассоциативный массив, в котором будут храниться элементы 2-го массива, отфильтрованные **по порядковому номеру элемента** одномерного массива.

Comment: А где какой то код или попытки решить вопрос?

Comment: 1. Через foreach обошёл 1-й массив, получил номера значений.
2. Дальше, думаю, надо использовать array_search либо array_filter на 2-й массив, но ума не приложу, как..

Comment: было что то подобное уже тут

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688629/223826

Answer (score 0):

1. Применяешь **[array_flip](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-flip.php)** для массива `$categories`, чтобы поменять местами ключи со значениями.
2. Пробегаешь по массиву `$pets` и добавляешь в каждый подмассив ключ `index` со значением, равному индексу в массиве `$categories`. Будет что-то типа такого:

   ```
    $pet[LOOP_COUNT]['index'] = $categories[$pet['type']];
   ```
3. Применяешь **[usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)**, чтобы отсортировать массив `$pet`, по полю `index`

> Мне нужно не отсортировать, а получить новый массив, содержащий только элементы определённого типа, который нужно взять из первого массива. Вижу решение через array_filter, но не хватает скилла, чтобы его допилить

1. Применяешь **[array_flip](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-flip.php)** для массива `$categories`, чтобы поменять местами ключи со значениями.
2. Применяешь **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)** относительно массива `$pets` с ключевым словом `use`, чтобы в callback функции был доступен массив `$categories` -
   http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php#100813
3. Фильтрацию производишь по условию существования ключа из `$pets`  в `$categories`, примерно так:

   ```
   isset($categories[$pet['type']]);
   ```

Comment: Мне нужно не отсортировать, а получить новый массив, содержащий только элементы определённого типа, который нужно взять из первого массива. Вижу решение через array_filter, но не хватает скилла, чтобы его допилить..

Comment: @IvanIvanovich ну так **по порядковому номеру элемента** - означает сортировку, а не фильтрацию....  либо вопрос неправильно описан, либо надо хотя бы ожидаемый `input` и `output` показать

Comment: Отфильтрованные != отсортированные.
Имел в виду отобранные в новый ассоциативный массив вида $pets = [0 => ['name' => 'Jacky', 'type' => 'Bird'], 1 => ['name' => 'Rich', 'type' => 'Bird']] по значению №0 1-го массива.

Comment: @IvanIvanovich `по значению №0 1-го массива`, тогда тебе достаточно в условии фильтра проверять если значение `type` равно нужному значению, то его и возвращать..... написал общий случай в ответе... но думаю догадаешься как из этого сделать более частный

Comment: @IvanIvanovich `Отфильтрованные != отсортированные` - поэтому и говорю, что вопрос сформулирован некорректно, потому что нельзя отфильтровать по порядковому номеру элемента, а лишь сортировать

Comment: Спасибо за указание направление, куда копать. Думаю, справлюсь